# how i can add telegram.ext class in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to create a bot but I can't import class of telegram.ext. I guess I did not install the necessary stuff

I installed python Environments anaconda 5.3.0, python 3.7 64-bit and 32-bit, python 3.6 64-bit. But I did not answer.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6M2I.jpg)

I can easily do this in PyCharm, but want to in Visual Studio as well.

Comment: You have installed different python environments. Most probably Visual Studio doesn't use the same environment as PyCharm. Try to change Visual Studio environment, or install `telegram.ext` pachage in all environments.

Comment: i install telegram.ext with pip and it solved thanks .

Answer (score 0):

try `pip install python-telegram-bot`